# Call REST webservice using Spring Integration and Oauth

Tags: spring-security, oauth, spring-integration, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

My goal is to perform a call to a REST webservice using an outbound gateway, this webservice needs a token provided by another web service.
I've tried using Spring oauth without any luck since I am not sure how to integrate both frameworks.

```
    <int:chain input-channel="requestChannel">
                <int-http:outbound-gateway
                url="https://webservice.url/..."
                http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                rest-template="restTemplate" />
                ... 
    </int:chain>

    <oauth:resource id="oauth1" client-id="admin"
        access-token-uri="https://token.priovider.url/..."
        client-secret="secret" client-authentication-scheme="header" type="password"
        scope="trust" password="mypassword" username="myusername" />

    <oauth:rest-template id="restTemplate" resource="oauth1" />
```

Token webservice response format:

```
{
   "signInResponse":{
      "duration":86400000,
      "token":"sKgRT6748UH0h_XEdIUYsUDSkBDUMKCW",
      "userName":"myusername",
      "userId":"http://identity.auth.service.com/100046",
      "idleTimeout":14400000
   }
}
```

While I was debugging I found in the following line (OAuth2RestTemplate constructor), the value of "context" is **"com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method."**:

```
public OAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context)
```

Comment: I have never used OAuth, but your configuration looks reasonable for me. What a problem do you have? How does it look? Maybe you there one more `restTemplate` which overrides this one for OAuth?

Comment: It would be better to do that like an `EDIT` to your qeustion. Otherwise it isn't readable from the comment. From other side `Property or field 'request' cannot be found on object of type` fully isn't related to the OAuth. That is something different. Please, don't mix concerns when you ask the question.

Comment: Are you sure about what type of token your target webservice really requires? Maybe it does not expect an OAuth token? Did you check that spring integration really uses the OAuth2RestTemplate instead of the standard RestTemplate?

Comment: Hi @andifalk, It's using OAuth2RestTemplate, I've updated my description with more details. The type of token my webservice requires is the one I mentioned before, which is provided by another webservice by passing username and password. I am not sure if I am using the right flow or components in my solution. Thank you.