# Regarding Retry with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I am calling a webservice in my Application which has authentication tokens that can expire.
In case of token expiry, I need to refresh the token and retry the webservice.
To do this, I felt spring retry might be the right candidate.
But I have no idea how to inject this refresh token service in between my retries.

Comment: Related: [Call REST webservice using Spring Integration and Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861053/476716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Retry is not what you want. That is for idempotent operations where you literally just try again.

Is this an OAuth token? Then you want [Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/).

Even if not you want to do the same thing that [`Oauth2RestTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.java) does: hook the token handling into the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Ok .. "idempotent operations"!!! The webservice has oauth tokens. We are currently using Spring Integration MessagingGateway to hit the webservice. Is there a way to inject Oauth functionality to these integration gateways? Please don't mind my noobness

Comment: The `int-http:outbound-gateway` appears to have a `restTemplate` parameter. That's probably how you integrate them.